# Basic philosophy of function pointer in callback

Tags: c, pointers, callback, function-pointers

To understand function pointer I am following [this](http://www.go4expert.com/articles/understanding-c-function-pointers-t26662/) tutorial 
This example is given there to demonstrate the purpose of function pointer:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int func(char *s)
{
    printf("Callback recieved : %s",s);
    return 0;
}

float divide(unsigned int a, unsigned int b, int(*status_callback)(char*))
{
    status_callback("\n Recieved values...validating\n");
    if(b == 0)
    {
        status_callback("\n b = 0 detected, aborting....\n");
        return -1;
    }
    status_callback("\n Validation complete, performing division\n");
    float ret = a/b;
    status_callback("\n Division complete, returning value\n");
    return ret;
}


int main(void)
{
    int(*func_ptr)(char*);
    unsigned int a = 6, b = 3;
    printf("\n This is a prgram to find a/b\n");

    func_ptr = func;

    float ret = divide(a,b,func_ptr);
    printf("\n divide returned [%f]\n",ret);

    return 0;

}
```

Here as per the author,the function 'divide()' can be thought of as a library function.

The output of the above:

```
This is a prgram to find a/b
Callback recieved : 
 Recieved values...validating
Callback recieved : 
 Validation complete, performing division
Callback recieved : 
 Division complete, returning value

 divide returned [2.000000]
```

Now I am unable to understand the basic philosophy of the function pointer being explained here. And my following code would also solve the same purpose (of informing the application what is happening at the library level):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

float divide(unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
        printf("\n Recieved values...validating\n");
        if(b == 0)
        {
                printf("\n b = 0 detected, aborting....\n");
                return -1;
        }
        printf("\n Validation complete, performing division\n");
        float ret = a/b;
printf("\n Division complete, returning value\n");
        return ret;
}


int main(void)
{
//      int(*func_ptr)(char*);
        unsigned int a = 6, b = 3;
        printf("\n This is a prgram to find a/b\n");

//      func_ptr = func;

        float ret = divide(a,b);
        printf("\n divide returned [%f]\n",ret);

        return 0;
```

The output of the above is:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/# ./a.out 

 This is a prgram to find a/b

 Recieved values...validating

 Validation complete, performing division

 Division complete, returning value

 divide returned [2.000000]
```

The same purpose is solved using printf statements. So why use function pointer ?

Comment: do not run normal programs as `root`. bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

The other important use of callback function pointers is receive asynchronous notifications when the required processing/information is not available immediately. This is common with OS API calls - you make the call, passing your function pointer and, sometime later, when the operation is complete, some OS thread calls your function.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, calling the function pointer is the same as just doing the code of `func` locally.

But the point is you could create different functions that behaved differently.  One could write to a file, another could call syslog, another save messages in a database.  Then they all could be passed to `divide` and it wouldn't care.  Its separating the writing of messages from the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Function pointer is just another method of calling a function from a function. This approach is mainly used when we cannot determine the exact function to be called at *complle time*. If , at *runtime*,  based on any previous compitation or returrned value, the function to be called has to be changed to obtain specific behaviour,  using function pointer comes handy.

Obviously, for simple cases, it might not *look* useful [use of `switch` cases, in contrast], but for more complex scenarios, using this approach makes the code more robust and readable.

Answer (score 0):

The reference you have given seems to be a little misleading. It explains `function pointers` as `callbacks` **without actually serving the purpose of a callback**. 
[This](http://www.prog2impress.com/downloads/The%20Function%20Pointer%20Tutorials.pdf) would be a better tutorial for `function pointers`. The `qsort()` library function is a good example of `callback`.